In this proposition why is $\approx$ used rather than $=$?
Proposition 1.1.3 Residuated Structures in Algebra and Logic by Metcalfe, Paoli, and Tsinakis states in part: There exists a bijective correspondence between lattices and algebras $\langle L, \wedge, \vee \rangle$ of signature $\langle 2, 2 \rangle$ satisfying the equations
\begin{align*}
  &\text{(L1.1)} &x \wedge (y \wedge z) \approx (x \wedge y) \wedge z \hspace{36pt} &\text{(L2.1)} &x \wedge (y \wedge z) \approx (x \wedge y) \wedge z
\end{align*}
(Similar equations for lattice properties are omitted)
Why have the authors used $\approx$ rather than $=$?

This seems strange.  Are you sure that the sense of $\approx$ has not been explained elsewhere in Residuated Structures in Algebra and Logic ?  [ Of course, these are intended as identities, not merely equations.]

@GEdgar This proposition occurs on page 3. I have looked through the pages several times.

I assume the predicate logic system the book uses doesn't define the meta $=$ symbol. They define an equal relation inside the system.

In universal algebra - or anywhere else that weak fragments of FOL, around the level of equational or Horn logic, are used - this is fairly standard notation for universally quantified equalities; that is, $$x*y\approx y*x$$ should be read as $$\forall x,y(x*y=y*x)$$ and so on. Similarly, the term "equation" usually means "universally quantified equality" in such contexts.
